# Is it OK for a child's bike to have a radially-laced rear wheel?

Tags: wheel-building, rear-wheel, children

I was looking at the [Early Rirder Belter 16" child's bike](http://earlyrider.com/collections/bikes/products/belter-16) and noticed that the rear wheel has radial spokes on both sides.

In wheels built for adult bikes this is [considered bad practice](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/wheelbuild.html#radial). From Sheldon Brown's site:-

> Wheels with hub brakes and drive wheels should never be radially
>   spoked. Due to the near-perpendicular angle of the spoke to the hub's
>   tangent, any torque applied at the hub of a radial-spoked wheel will
>   result in a very great increase in spoke tension, almost certainly
>   causing hub or spoke failure.

These bikes seem to be popular and get good reviews, so it seems that this isn't an issue in practice. Is this because of the small wheels and the fact that children don't produce so much torque?

[image]

Comment: You said it -- small wheel and not much torque.  And the bikes aren't really expected to last that long, since they're outgrown so quickly and kids' bikes are far more likely to come to a dismal end being run over in the garage or some such.

Comment: Its probably going to depend on the child's weight, and what they do with the bike.

Comment: Radial spokes on the drive side of a rear wheel and on any side of a disk-brake wheel come under heavy stress. On an adult bike they will certainly fail. On a child's bike they might survive (lower weight, lower pedal power, lower brake force) They have probably been used because radial spoked wheels are quicker to build an therefore cheaper.

Comment: It looks like the spokes aren't completely radial and that there is a single crossing very close to the hub.

Comment: @Kibbee. I looked at one in a shop and they really don't cross. Checking this image you can see the gap. http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTIwMFgxNjAw/z/iwUAAOSw5VFWK6HV/$_57.JPG

Comment: @JamesBradbury Appears you are right.  It's a little optical illusion I guess when you view it straight on because you're seeing the spokes on both sides of the hub and it looks like spokes are crossing.

Comment: At 290 UKP that's definitely not a BSO!  Its got a drive belt and decent tektro brake calipers!

Comment: Actually, they are diagonally laced, to a degree, just not crossed.  The mere fact that the hubs are drilled with holes aligned vs offset produces a diagonal lacing.  What you don't have is lacing that balances the "diagonality" on both sides -- the spokes are tugging forwards on one side and backwards on the other.  (On a wheel so small, with spokes maybe 5" long, there's simply no room for "crossing".)

Comment: (In my bike repair work I've never seen a 12-16 inch wheel that was damaged, other than due to being run over by a car or some such.  It's fairly common to see a 20-24 inch wheel that is damaged, though, apparently from doing stunts.  But these larger wheels, to my recollection, are always "properly" interlaced (and the damage is almost always to the front wheel, not the rear).)

Comment: The similar Cnoc14 has 1-cross spokes, so it _can_ be done, but I guess it doesn't make much difference. https://www.islabikes.co.uk/products/bikes/item/cnoc-14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a kids bike where the rider weight is under 25 kilograms / 50 pounds a radial spoked wheel is fine.

I've been trying to clean up and true an old 12" steel wheel with radial spokes and I'm truly astonished how strong it is.  The spokes themselves are identical to normal bike spokes, just the length that is different.  The cross sectional area is the same.

The rim is normally the same profile as a bigger wheel too, just with more curve on it.  This also contributes to the smaller wheel's overall strength.

I'd say a 16" would be fine, but a 20" and above should be properly laced.
If the rider is... over 25 kilos then perhaps a cheap wheel is inappropriate.
The rider will probably outgrow the bike frame in height before they get too heavy for it.